# npm audit fix --force returns npm ERR! Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: node.js, npm

While giving command npm audit fix --force I am getting this error

```
npm WARN dev @ngneat/spectator@"^5.13.4" from the root project
npm ERR! Cannot convert undefined or null to object

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

for fixing this I have tried this command

```
npm config get registry
```

I got this result https://registry.npmjs.org/
So I think this is ok, any other solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

Using `npm install --no-audit` worked for me.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck